# Restrict Field Access at Application Level

Tags: salesforce-classic

I have a requirement where I have two application both using same object but I need a field to be present in one object of first application but it should be hidden in another application using same object.Profiles and user is same.Can anybody please let me know is it possible to do in salesforce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Lightning Experience you can have app specific layouts but not in Classic.

In Classic you would have to build a Visualforce page to achieve this but AFAIK that would also need some hacky JavaScript to find the currently selected app in the drop-down list at the top right of the screen:

```
var appName = document.getElementById("tsidLabel").innerText;
```

and then some more JavaScript to show/hide the field. The need to hide the field would have to be really important to make this worth doing.